# getFormula() and setFormula() to multiple ranges

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy all formulas from one sheet (January) to multiple sheets (February, March, April, etc.) in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script.
The below code is doing what I want for cell A1.
However, I would like to copy ALL formulas (or let's say A1:Z10) from sheet January to their respective cell in the target sheet.

```
function copyFormula(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("February");
  var fromRange = sheet.getRange("January!A1");
  var toRange2 = sheet.getRange("February!A1");
  var toRange3 = sheet.getRange("March!A1");
  var toRange4 = sheet.getRange("April!A1");
  var toRange5 = sheet.getRange("May!A1");
  toRange2.setFormula(fromRange.getFormula());
  toRange3.setFormula(fromRange.getFormula());
  toRange4.setFormula(fromRange.getFormula());
  toRange5.setFormula(fromRange.getFormula());
}
```

In addition to this, I am sure that there is a better way to write this: i. e. something like `var toRange = sheet.getRange("February!A1","March!A1","April!A1","May!A1");` and       `toRange.setFormula(fromRange.getFormula());` instead of creating individual variables for each month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to become simpler your script.
- You want to copy the formulas of cells "A1:Z10" of `January` sheet to the cells "A1:Z10" in each sheet.

#### Sample script 1:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the RangeList cannot be used for different sheets in the same Google Spreadsheet. So in this sample script, the source formula is put to the cell of each sheet using a loop.

```
function copyFormula(){
  var sheets = ["February","March","April","May"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceFormulas = ss.getSheetByName("January").getRange("A1:Z10").getFormulas();
  sheets.forEach(s => ss.getSheetByName(s).getRange("A1:Z10").setFormulas(sourceFormulas));
}
```

- If you want to increase the sheets, please modify `sheets`.

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, Sheets API is used. Because I thought that the process cost of above script is a bit high, because the `setFormula` is used in a loop. In this sample script, the process cost will be a bit lower than above one. When you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google servicies](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function copyFormula(){
  var ranges = ["February!A1:Z10","March!A1:Z10","April!A1:Z10","May!A1:Z10"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceFormulas = ss.getSheetByName("January").getRange("A1:Z10").getFormulas();
  var values = ranges.map(r =>({values: sourceFormulas, range: r}));
  var resource = {responseValueRenderOption:"FORMULA",valueInputOption:"USER_ENTERED",data:values};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

- If you want to increase the sheets, please modify `ranges`.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)